# Not able to connect to mongodb running in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I have a mongoDB DB container running and I'am not able to connect to it using Robo 3T, I get the folowing error.

[image]

[image: Container is running and waiting for connection at 27017]

[image: Docker ps shows the same]

[image: connection settings in robo 3T]

Any help on what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `PORTS` column of the docker ps output :

```
PORTS
27017/tcp
```

No mapping is specified (`->` symbol).   It means that the container port is not published outside the docker networks.

Two possible ways to solve your issue :

- Don't specify localhost as hostname but the container ip : you can retrieve it with `docker inspect CONTAINER`.   If you use cygwin : `docker inspect CONTAINER | grep IPAddress`.
- publish the mongo container port on the host machine.  You can publish it on the same port or not with the `-p` arg such as `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`.
  For example with the same port :  `docker run -d -p 27017:27017  mongo:latest`.

You could see with docker ps that the port is published on the host now :

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind mongodb port to your docker host to access it using localhost from the host -

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 ....
```

I suspect you are missing `-p 27017:27017`.